# The Koszul complex

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, book-recommendation

I want to read about the Koszul complex and its properties. Someone asked a similar question but he recived a book recommendation which doesn't help me.

I saw that there exists two constructions, one with exterior power and the other with tensor product of complexes.

There is some reference with a easy, clear, concise and complete explanation about it?

Comment: How about Eisenbud's book on commutative algebra?

Comment: Wikipedia seems pretty great to me, tbh: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_complex

Comment: @Ravi I need  the proofs of the properties.

Comment: In what *context* are you intending to read about the Koszul complex? There are at least two (if not more) places where it may appear and be used. In the commutative setting, there's the classical Koszul complex, which you can modify to obtain resolutions of says quotient algebras of polynomial rings. In the non-commutative case, you have the Koszul complex of a quadratic algebra and its Koszul dual, which specializes to the classical Koszul complex of commutative algebra.

Comment: You can find accounts of the Koszul complex in McCleary's *User's guide to spectral sequences*, in Lang's *Algebra*, in Eisebud's *Homological Algebra* and in Weibel's *Introduction to Homological Algebra*, among others. Those should give varied viewpoints of the use of the complex.